# Glimpse - odd ms numbers reported

Tags: glimpse

Am I missing something with **ms** timings Glimpse displays?

It reported a Request time of 30684 ms - but the page definitely didn't take 30 seconds to load.

Using Glimpse 1.4.2, Glimpse AspNet 1.3.1 and Glimpse Mvc3 1.3.2.

Comment: It does that on every refresh of that page or only on the first initial start-up after a rebuild? Can you reproduce it in a separate project? If so, could you then open an issue on the [Glimpse issue tracker](https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse/issues)?

Answer (score 0):

The request time, as show in the heads up display, includes both the server side rendering time and the client side rendering time.

Is it possible that your page's onload event was not triggered until ~30 seconds in? (For example, is a 3rd party widget loading slowly?)